# cadence workflow in case of cadence outage

Tags: go, cadence-workflow

It is possible to run local *activities* that don't require a connection to the [cadence](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) server. Is there a proper way to run *workflows* locally, too, in case of a cadence outage? 
I'm using the Go client.

Answer (score 1):

The service connection is required to make any progress in the workflow execution including scheduling activities.

To run workflows locally you can use local version of the Cadence service. Such version can be easily installed through docker compose.

If you need high availability setup you can use multi-cluster Cadence. So a single cluster outage is not going to cause workflow execution outager.

Comment: but you can run local activities that skips scheduling, so if I don't use any of the state-full aspect of the workflow would be nice to have a fail-over version.

Comment: Local activity results are still checkpointed to to Cadence. So I wouldn't rely on them for higher availability.